# Interpolate a series missing values based on another series

Tags: pandas, scipy, time-series, data-science, interpolation

I have this data:

```
{
"col1" : [1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,8],
"col2" : [2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2]
"col_macro" : [3,4,7,7,13,18]
}
```

Both data columns are time series. `col1` and `col2` column are micro-data and `col_macro` is macro data
I want to replace missing values with interpolation using the `col_macro`. Meaning that rate of change and the shocks should be similar between them.

Also is there a way where I can put restrictions? for instance I want the interpolation strictly increase, decreasing or unchanged if the values at both end are similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
"col1" : [1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,8],
"col2" : [2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2],
"col_macro" : [3,4,7,7,13,18]
})
```

find the consecutive differences in col3, use combined_first  to pass to right column. Because its consecutive difference, do an expanding sum

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].combine_first(df['col_macro'].diff()).expanding(1).sum()
df['col2'] = df['col1'].combine_first(df['col_macro'].diff()).expanding(1).sum()
```

Comment: Thank you! it works like a charm! but I think there is a typo on second line. It is using col1 for col2.